# POX and SOAP on the same endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, soap

I have a requirement where I need to expose the service for both SOAP and POX incoming requests.I included the following code snippet to switch from SOAP to POX and it worked fine

```
@Bean(name = MessageDispatcherServlet.DEFAULT_MESSAGE_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME)
public WebServiceMessageFactory messageFactory() {
    return new DomPoxMessageFactory();
}
```

But to make the application accept SOAP requests I commented the above code.
Obviously,its not the desired solution and I need my application to accept both SOAP and POX without this code change.Can you please suggest a proper approach?

Comment: Could anyone please suggest me an approach?.I am struggling to find a solution for it